# VBA to copy x (variable) rows to another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

Gods of VBA,

Have been trying all morning to tweak this piece of amateur-VBA (in which case i'm the amateur) to perform as i want.

What is does now is the following; Looks for cell value 1 in Column O on the third sheet in my workbook. When it gets a hit, it copies the row which has 1 in Column O to a new worksheet called "Blad1". It then switches back to my 3rd sheet in the workbook "Doorvoeren".

It will loop and perform the task as wanted, only thing i can't get it to do is copy rows based on a variable in sheet "Doorvoeren". When this value is 5, i want it to copy the row with 1 in column O, and the 4 rows below it. (as example).

Could you please send me in the right direction here? Trying to make it work, but also learn from it in the process.

My code is added in the sample below:

```
Sub testIt()
Dim r As Long, endRow As Long, pasteRowIndex As Long

endRow = 500
pasteRowIndex = 5

For r = 3 To endRow

    If Cells(r, Columns("O").Column).Value = 1 Then
            Rows(r).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Blad1").Select
            Rows(pasteRowIndex).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            pasteRowIndex = pasteRowIndex + 1
            Sheets("Doorvoeren").Select
    End If
Next r
End Sub
```

EDIT: Thank you all for your answers, actually having real trouble to find one that works. To explain again; I need this VBA tweaked in the way that it looks at cell Q3, in sheet "Doorvoeren" to get the number of rows to copy. So, if Q3 is cell value; 5, i want it to to copy the row with number 1 in Column O, in Sheet "Doorvoeren", but also the other four rows below it.

So my 1 in Column O, is just a marker, not the number of rows i want to copy.
Please ask/tell me if i'm not being totally clear.

Comment: Hi. Which column is the variable in on your "Doorvoeren" sheet? And is the variable always an integer that indicates how may roaws it should copy below it? (so for example, there are 1's where only one row needs copying, 2's where two rows etc etc)

Comment: The variable is in Sheet "Doorvoeren" Q3, this is always an integer number. When it hits 1, (which is my marker everytime), i want it to copy the number of rows of the value in Q3. Hope this clears it up.

Comment: `rows(r).resize(Q3 VALUE).copy`

Comment: @RobExcel try the code in my answer below, see if it works as you intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution (slightly ammending your code with annotations)

```
Sub testIt()

'add another variable (called var)

Dim r As Long, endRow As Long, pasteRowIndex As Long, Var As Long

endRow = 500
pasteRowIndex = 5

For r = 3 To endRow

    If Cells(r, Columns("O").Column).Value = 1 Then

'Grab the var number from the Doorvoeren sheet. Var will then determine how many rows need to be copied in each circumstance

            Sheets("Doorvoeren").Select
            Var = Cells(r, Columns("Q").Column).Value

            Rows(r & ":" & r + (Var - 1)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Blad1").Select
            Rows(pasteRowIndex).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            pasteRowIndex = pasteRowIndex + Var
            Sheets("Doorvoeren").Select

    End If

Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your really quick answer @Wilson88. Made an edit, trying to explain my problem better in my original post, i think your code is closest to working.

Comment: No prob. In reference to your edit, I have not used the marker to define the number of rows to copy, but the value in column Q (as per the comments in your original post). Var = Cells(r, Columns("Q").Column).Value. Is this not correct?

Comment: Ding, ding, ding. We have a winner. Sorry for misunderstanding Wilson, brilliant solution to the problem!

Comment: No, your code is perfect at what i want. Just understood it completely wrong. Think i've been doing VBA for too many hours today.

Comment: @RobExcel you do realize that using `Select` between the sheets all the time is not the best solution, right ?

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended if you avoid using `Select` and `ActiveSheet`, instead use referenced Sheets and Ranges.

```
Option Explicit

Sub testIt()

Dim r As Long, endRow As Long, pasteRowIndex As Long
Dim PasteRow As Long

With Sheets("Doorvoeren")
    ' find last row with data in Column "O" in "Doorvoeren" sheet
    endRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row

    For r = 3 To endRow
        If .Cells(r, "O").Value = 1 Then
            pasteRowIndex = 1
        Else
            If .Cells(r, "O").Value = 5 Then
                pasteRowIndex = 5
            End If
        End If

        ' find last row with data in Column "O" in "Blad1" sheet
        PasteRow = Sheets("Blad1").Cells(Sheets("Blad1").Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row

        ' copy number of rows from "Doorvoeren" sheet to "Blad1" sheet, paste them on the first empty row in "Blad1" sheet
        .Range("O" & r).Resize(pasteRowIndex).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Blad1").Range("A" & PasteRow + 1)
    Next r    
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your really quick answer @Shai Rado. Made an edit, trying to explain my problem better in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

I made a slight change upon your explanation.

```
'====================================================
Sub testIt()
    Dim r As Long, endRow As Long, pasteRowIndex As Long
    Dim DestR as Range
    Dim Rloop as Range
    dim RowsCounter as Integer

    endRow = 500
    pasteRowIndex = 5
    RowsCounter = 0

    For Each Rloop in Sheets("Doorvoeren").range("O3:O" & endRow)
        if Rloop = 1 and RowsCounter=0 then RowsCounter = Rloop.Offset(0, 2)
        If Rloop = 1 or RowsCounter > 0 Then

                Set DestR = Sheets("Blad1").range("A" & pasteRowIndex)
                Rloop.EntireRow.Copy DestR
                pasteRowIndex = pasteRowIndex + 1
                RowsCounter = RowsCounter - 1
        End If
    Next Rloop
End Sub
```

Hope this helps better :)

Comment: Thank you for your really quick answer @Hadi.  Made an edit, trying to explain my problem better in my original post.

Comment: Let me know if you have any question about this.